# Firebase Tools error after upgrade

Tags: firebase

After upgrading to v3.6.1, now when I run 'firebase serve', I get this error:

```
TypeError: Not an integer
    at Object.fs.writeSync (fs.js:540:18)
    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:114:10)
    at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:62:21)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:11)
    at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:34:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:123:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase:5:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Trying to reinstall firebase-tools, I get these:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN engine csv-streamify@3.0.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine rsvp@3.5.0: wanted: {"node":"0.12.* || 4.* || 6.* || 7.*"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine request@2.81.0: wanted: {"node":">= 4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN engine har-validator@4.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine form-data@2.1.4: wanted: {"node":">= 0.12"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine har-schema@1.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@2.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine boom@2.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine co@4.6.0: wanted: {"iojs":">= 1.0.0","node":">= 0.12.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Manually installed the latest version of node from http://nodejs.org/